# ruby catch connection timeout error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mechanize

I am using Mechanize in Ruby to post forms to a site to obtain data. Occasionally, I will get the error

```
too many connection resets (due to Operation timed out - Errno::ETIMEDOUT) after 13 requests on 34234234234242, last used 20.518373 seconds ago
```

This will crash the server. I would like to catch this error and handle it(by retrying later on).

I tried

```
 begin 
    postForm(form)
  rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
    puts "=====>TimeOut ERROR!:"  
  end
```

But it is not catching the error. 
What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to Put one more rescue Exception=>e

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mechanize caught the `Errno::ETIMEDOUT` error and threw a new exception containing the error message. Therefore, the exception class name is different, and can't be caught with `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`.

To determine the type of error, try this:

```
begin 
  postForm(form)
rescue => e
  puts e.class  
end
```

That will give you the exception class name, and you can update the rescue clause.

Comment: this will not catch all the exceptions, but only those that inherit from `StandardError`. it's better to use `rescue Exception => e`

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer it's considered bad practice to catch `Exception`, because it breaks certain behaviour (like signals, Ctrl-C, etc) and can cause your program to continue running when there are good reasons why it should stop. If there's a specific exception that you need to catch that doesn't inherit from `StandardError`, best to specify it directly.

Comment: yea, that's right. so you can just raise the exception again if it's a signal. `raise e if e.is_a?(Interrupt)`

Comment: Ok, signals was just an example. There are loads of exceptions that you definitely don't want to catch, including `NoMemoryError`, `SyntaxError`, `LoadError` and `SystemStackError`. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html

Comment: My comment is according to your own answer. You want to catch all the exceptions just to know the exception class that cause that problem. For this catching `Exception` is the best way. this is because all the exceptions inherits from it. But the way you suggested would not catch some of the exceptions. Once you know the list of exceptions you want to handle, you can put them in an  array and handle them this way `rescue *exceptions_array => e`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the entire error message, you see that you failed because of a 'too many connection resets' : The timeout is only what caused the connection to reset 13 times, and has already been rescued.

So if you read the source of Net-Http-persistent [>here<](https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent/blob/master/lib/net/http/persistent.rb#L1040), you will see that the error you need to catch is :

```
Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error
```